# How do i change input field background color based on onclick?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want to change the input field back-ground color based on gender selection.

So far I have:

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $("#male").click(function(){
    $("#gender").css("backgroundColor:#0000FF");
 }); 
</script> 

<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $("#female").click(function(){
    $("#gender").css("backgroundColor:#FFC0CB");
 }); 
</script> 

<form>
 <label for="gender">Gender:</label>
 <select id="gender" name="gender">
   <option value="male" selected>Male</option>
   <option value="female">Female</option>
 </select><br>
</form>
```

This has not been working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can have this is a JavaScript function and call it with `onchange=` like this

```js
function changeColor(el) {
if (el.value == "male")
{
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#0000FF";
  }
if (el.value == "female")
{
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#FFC0CB";
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<form>
 <label for="gender">Gender:</label>
 <select id="gender" name="gender" onchange="changeColor(this)">
   <option disabled selected value> -- select an option -- </option>
   <option value="male">Male</option>
   <option value="female">Female</option>
 </select><br>
</form>
```

Comment: Huh? OP wants gender selection not color selection in the <select>. Arbitrarily changing the option values to fit your code doesn't make sense

Comment: @charlietfl oh i see, ok i have updated my code

Answer (score 0):

Events are not supported on `<option>` element cross browser

You want to use change event of the select then conditionally set color based on new value.

Also note your syntax for `css()` is not quite right

```js
$("#gender").change(function() {
  const color = this.value === 'female' ? '#FFC0CB' : '#0000FF';
  $(this).css('backgroundColor', color)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <label for="gender">Gender:</label>
  <select id="gender" name="gender">
    <option value="male" selected>Male</option>
    <option value="female">Female</option>
  </select><br>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the current **option:selected** ***value*** using `$(#gender option:selected).val()` then set it using the elements **tag** *selector*. In your change function you can access the element using `$(this)`. Use a conditinal to see if it is set to `$(this).val() === "male"` ==> `$(this).css("background-color", "lightblue")` if not set to female `$(this).css("background-color", "pink")` by default as that is your only other option.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#gender option:selected').val() === "male" ? $('#gender').css("background-color", "lightblue") :  $('#gender').css("background-color", "pink")
  
  $("#gender").change(function(e) {
    $(this).val() === "male" ? $(this).css("background-color", "lightblue") : $(this).css("background-color", "pink")
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<form>
  <label for="gender">Gender:</label>
  <select id="gender" name="gender">
    <option value="male" selected>Male</option>
    <option value="female">Female</option>
  </select><br>
</form>
```